# Django Show user that upload is in progress

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a filemanager application that allows users to upload files to the server and ofcourse download them. Now in the state it is when an user starts uploading the browser only shows that small loading circle until upload is finished. And the usage for this server would be for quite big files, mostly about 100mb so it can take some time and unexperienced users might start browsing around while uploading and ruining it.

I have been looking into progressbars but I'm not such an avid coder and it would take some time for me to implement that in my filemanager application. Time I might not have really. I have been thinking of a notification for the user, for example an alert box with text saying: "Uploading, please wait!" while it is uploading, and the box would disappear when upload is finished. I allready tried with a javascript alert box but that just requires user to click ok and then it does the same.

```
def upload(request):
if request.POST:
    post_data = request.POST.copy()

if not post_data.get('path'):
        return raise_error(request,
            [_(u"No path given")])
    if not post_data['path'].startswith(request.user.fileman_Setting.root):
        return raise_error(request,
            [_(u"No access")])

    post_data.update(request.FILES)
    form = UploadForm(post_data)
    if form.is_valid():
       form.save(request.FILES, request)
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/fm/list/%s' % form.path)
    else:
        return raise_error(request,
            form.errors)
else:
    return raise_error(request,
            [_(u"Empty form.")])
```

Any ideas how I could implement something to notify the user that it is uploading and he should wait? Something way simpler than a progressbar. I've been thinking of using that HttpResponseRedirect in the end as a mark that upload is complete, can I do something with that together with something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post: http://kuhlit.blogspot.com/2011/04/ajax-file-uploads-and-csrf-in-django-13.html discusses how to implement an upload progress bar for Django 1.3. I think a progress bar would be preferable, although if you wanted to do something simple, you could just show a dialog with javascript saying, "HEY I'M UPLOADING HERE".